# What is a scab and why is being one so bad?

Tags: pilots

I understand that a generally speaking a scab is someone who crosses a picket line. In aviation, however, there seems to be [severe opposition](https://forums.jetcareers.com/threads/what-is-a-scab-in-the-airline-pilot-world.6686/) (hatred?) toward flying flying with a scab, to the point of swapping legs. There also seems to be some pretty strong public shaming through publication of [personal data](https://www.cockpitseeker.com/wp-content/uploads/posts/wikileaks-airline-pilot-scab-list-2004.pdf).

**So: What is the origin of this stigma and why has it become so bad?**

(Caveat: I have no experience with unions, so this may be entirely normal and I just haven't had the exposure. If that is the case, please indoctrinate me.)

Comment: This is nothing to do with aviation.

Comment: The question hints at something like "is their reputation especially bad in aviation," which could be on topic, but that sounds like it could be too opinion-based.

Comment: Mainly language related and potentially opinion based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scab is a [strikebreaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikebreaker), an individual hired by a company to do work performed by unionized workers that are on strike, or a union member who rebels from his union and goes to work while there is a strike, crossing his own picket line.

In an airline context, if there is a pilots' strike, some pilots who are union members may decide to cross their own picket line and go against their union in order to keep flying, especially if they feel the strike is unjustified, or they are financially on the edge.

As emotions are usually high during these sorts of things and a lot is at stake, those who cross are seen as "traitors" by the rank and file who made the sacrifices you might say.  After the strike the pilots who went out and the pilots who crossed still have to work together, but the ones who went out will be very resentful of the ones who crossed.

Most will just sort of let it go and carry on, but there are always hotheads who will want to punish the rebels, hence the personal sanction campaigns, intended to make the picket line crossers think twice about doing it again.

Answer (score 2):

#### First a general answer, and then specifics

The problem with the "scab" as seen by a union member - during a labor dispute between management and the {pilot's} union - is that the "scab" is directly undermining the leverage and bargaining capacity of the  union that has a work stoppage as one of the tools available for negotiation of a wide variety of things.

This is consistent with union activity going back about a century in the American labor movement.  (My answer can only really speak to American labor movement.  I am not sure how this fits all other countires, but my limited experience in Italy 20+ years ago is that their unions were generally much stronger).  My dad was a union member for a few years in the steel industry in the Western Pennsylvania.

The disputes that come to that point that leads to a threat - stoppage of operations - are usually the result of management and the union coming to an impasse that needs to be overcome in order to arrive at a new contract/collective bargaining agreement/pay scale, whatever the issue is.

The "scab" pilot (or a whole bunch of them) give management a get out of jail free card rather then keeping negotiation going (in good faith or bad).  That means that the "scabs" have taken money out of the pockets of all union members (or so a union member's perspective will often go), not only in the short term but in the longer term for all members of that union if it gets the union to back down and accept a lesser settlement.

That has *serious long term implications on quality of life* for thousands of pilots if it breaks the strike.

Yeah: some long term ill will can be accrued.

#### Specifics from my life experience:

When Frank Lorenzo was engaged in union busting with Continental in the 80's, there was some bad blood between some of the recent hires and those who had been there for a longer time.  I knew people in both camps who were reservists who flew with us (I was in the Navy, they were in the reserve unit supporting our squadron).     What I saw, in person, was the "we don't speak with X" played out in our squadron over what was going on at Continental.

I won't start with the Teamsters, with whom I had a very small amount of RL experience.  I'll just say that shunning is a powerful peer influence tool.

Aside:  My father has some rougher stories about people (scabs) who got beaten to a pulp for crossing a picket line back in the 40's.